# how to properly send push notifications

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

This is not my first app sending push notifications but it is my first app where I send a notification to all my users at the same time.

What Im experiencing is that not all my users receive the notification, only some of them, even though they have the settings correct(ie notifications for my app enabled), also the code is correct since it is sent to some of them, so my guess is that the code "misses" some executions, since the conection with the APNS is asyncronous so somehow( you tell me if im wrong) that it messes the queue of sending notifications.

Here's the code:

```
function sendNotification(){

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone = 'iPhone' AND pushID != ''";
try {
    $db = getConnection();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
    $stmt->execute();
    $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $content = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $message = $content->message;

    foreach($users as $user){

            // Put your device token here (without spaces):
            $deviceToken = $user->pushID;


            // Put your private key's passphrase here:
            $passphrase = 'xxxxxxx';

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            $ctx = stream_context_create();
            stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'xxxxx.pem');
            stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

            // Open a connection to the APNS server
            $fp = stream_socket_client(
                'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
                $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

            if (!$fp)
                exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

            echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

            // Create the payload body
            $body['aps'] = array(
                'alert' => $message,
                'sound' => 'default'
                );

            // Encode the payload as JSON
            $payload = json_encode($body);

            // Build the binary notification
            $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

            // Send it to the server
            $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

            if (!$result)
                echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
            else
                echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

            // Close the connection to the server
            fclose($fp);

    }
    $db = null;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}
}
```

As you can see I fetch all my users with an iPhone and I send them the notification. My phone is the last user in that list and I didnt get it, another user that I know is one of the first ones and she got it.
It either misses some of the users in the array or it just does the first half, no error is shown.

Im using Slim for this.

hope you can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that some of the device tokens you are sending to are invalid. Even one invalid device can explain what you are experiencing. When you send a notification with an invalid device token, Apple returns an error response and closes the socket.

It's possible that by the time your code detects that the socket is closed you already sent many notifications after the invalid one (it's even possible you finished sending all the notifications before detecting the socket is closed), which causes all of the notifications sent after the invalid one to be discarded. Such notifications must be resent to Apple after you create a new socket.

I suggest you read the `Push Notification Throughput and Error Checking` section in [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html) for further details.

Make sure that your database doesn't contain a mix of production device tokens and sandbox device tokens, since production tokens are invalid in sandbox environment and vice versa.

Comment: I had the same problem here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116249/batch-multiple-ios-push-notification-code-works-for-2-devices-but-not-for-1 . It was indeed one bad device token at the top of my db table that was stopping notifications being sent to every device.

Comment: I tried just now to send a notification to all my users but through the sandox mode, which should have given an error, since none of my tokens are development and unluclily what I got was "Message succesfully sent", does really apple answer anything but "ALL OK"?

Comment: @subharb It depends how many notifications you send and how fast. If you send, for example, 10 notifications at the same time (and some of them with invalid device tokens), it's likely you won't see any exception and it would seem to you that they were all sent successfully. The next time you try to send notifications through the same socket you'll get an exception. Apple never answers "ALL OK". It only sends a response when an error occurs and only if you use the enhanced binary format. Read the link I supplied in my answer for more details.

Comment: @Eran Ok, now I understand what's going on. If you see my code I save the answer from Apple in $result, I supose that's going to be an integer or a boolean. Now Im printing the value of $result and that's either 138, if OK, or 139 if there was a problem, but from Apple's documentation I see that they actually send a binary number, but I can't find the way to make result be a binary number like the one in the documentation, can you help me out to get that binary number?
Thanks!

Comment: @subharb Based on your code (`chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;`) you are using the basic binary format, in which Apple return nothing. I don't know PHP, so I don't know what `fwrite` returns, but I wouldn't be surprised if it returns the number of bytes written, which only tells you if the bytes were sent to Apple. It doesn't tell you if the message you sent was valid. If you want responses from Apple you have to switch to the enhanced format and attempt to read from the socket.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to send a notification to multiple users using this below code. The below code helps you to send [Firebase push notification android](https://trinitytuts.com/firebase-push-notification-android/). You need to pass your server key and message to this function.

```
<?php
$target = ["TARGET_ID"];

$notificationBody['data'] = [
    'type' => 1,
    'url' => "https://trinitytuts.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/macaw.png",
    'title' => "title",
    "msg" => "Message"
];

$response = sendMessage($notificationBody, $target, $_POST['serverKey']);

function sendMessage($data, $target, $serverKey){
    //FCM api URL
    $rsp = [];
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    //api_key available in Firebase Console -> Project Settings -> CLOUD MESSAGING -> Server key
    $server_key = $serverKey;
    $fields = array();
    $fields['data'] = $data;
    if(is_array($target)){
            $fields['registration_ids'] = $target;
        }else{
            $fields['to'] = $target;
    }
    //header with content_type api key
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type:application/json',
        'Authorization:key='.$server_key
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        //die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    //print_r($result);
    return $result;
}
```